# How to use for loop to add the previous values in an array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have an array like `t`. It contains the numbers and I would like to add to each number the previous ones. For example: `t=[0,2,3,5]` and I would like to get `tnew=[0,2,5,10]`. I tried out this code but it is wrong for sure. (There are 5292 values)

```
for i=0:5292
    t(i)=t(i)+t(i+1)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some array `t = [0,2,3,5];`, you can just do `tnew = cumsum(t)`.

If you really want to do this in a loop, you need to start from the 2nd index, and keep adding to the value from the previous index

```
t = [0,2,3,5];
tnew = t;
for ii = 2:numel(t)
    tnew(ii) = t(ii) + tnew(ii-1);
end
```